# Nested 'for' loops not iterating through multiple items in a list (Python)

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to write a function that will read through a list of users from one file and then a list of tasks assigned to those users in a different file, producing statistics about the number of tasks assigned to each user (number completed, number overdue, etc).  The issue I'm having is that the code only works for the first user in the list of usernames. It gets to the second user and just stops iterating completely.

The problem specifically seems to be in the `for line in tasks_list:` section, this doesnt iterate for any users beyond the first. So Greg's `total_user_assigned_tasks` value increases while the other users' `total_user_assigned_tasks` stays at 0, even though Jake should have 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

This is the contents of the user.txt file:

```
Greg;Password
Jake;Password
Sam;Password
```

And this is the contents of the tasks.txt file:

```
Greg;Shopping;long;1994-07-17;2024-02-04;No
Greg;Cleaning;pop;1994-07-17;2024-02-04;Yes
Jake;Sweeping;ip;1994-07-17;2024-02-04;No
Greg;Driving;ip;1994-07-17;2024-02-04;Yes
Jake;Cooking;ip;2025-07-17;2024-02-04;No
```

This is the function:

```py
with open('tasks.txt', 'r') as tasks_list:
    with open('user.txt','r') as user_list:
        for line in user_list:             
            i = line.index(';')
            user = line[:i] 
            list_of_usernames.append(user)
    
    for person in list_of_usernames:
        total_user_assigned_tasks = 0
        total_user_completed_tasks = 0
        total_user_uncompleted_tasks = 0
        total_user_overdue_tasks = 0

        for line in tasks_list:    
            i = line.index(';')
            task_assigned_to = line[:i]        
    
            if person == task_assigned_to:
                total_user_assigned_tasks += 1
```